# Django： ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2' on Mac

Tags: django, postgresql

I have installed psycopg2-binary 2.9.1(pip install psycopg2-binary) in virtualenv, but when I execute python manage.py migrate, that appears "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'", and python console also can't import psycopg2. how to fix the problem?

Comment: `pip install psycopg2`

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my problem by use `python3 manage.py migrate`.